# Adding applications section under "Sound" as an indicator

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, indicator, spotify, amixer

May i learn any way to achieve that via a GUI indicator and have a sound mixer for each of the applications (such as spotify and skype) to set the volume differently?? Think the section shown on picture as an indicator.

Thank you so much.

[image]

ps: alsa mixer from terminal is not handy for daily usage, access to settings is much more easier than that mixer.

Answer (score 0):

To have a somewhat better control on presently playing output devices we may install and run [**pavucontrol**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pavucontrol) [image: Install banshee].

[image]

Comment: does it have indicator at  top?

Comment: No, it does not come with an own application indicator. If we must we could abuse the sound indicator to start pavucontrol by adding `pavucontrol` to the dconf key `com.canonical.indicator.sound/interested-media-players`. But it is not meant to be operated like that, and there is no advantage over starting from the launcher. I would not recommend to do so.

Comment: thanks for the advice m8, however it is no use to me. That just adds a bit features but not what i'm looking for.